# Creating default object from empty value using $this in a class

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I'm using a slight variation on the PHP PDO Wrapper Class found here: http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/

This is the new constructor I'm using:

```
public function __construct($dsn, $user='', $passwd='') {
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    try {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

`error` is a private variable of this class, defined at the begin of the class, above the constructor.strong text

And when I use it like this

```
$database = new Database(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['mysql_host'] . ';port=' . $config['mysql_port'] . ';dbname=' . $config['mysql_database'],
        $config['mysql_username'],
        $config['mysql_password']
);
```

It shows me this error: **Creating default object from empty value**, pointing to the database class file, at the line `$this->error = $e->getMessage();`.

The reason an exception is thrown is because I haven't set the mysql username and password yet, so don't worry about that. I'm trying to figure out why it gives this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, first of all provide username and password. Do you still get that error? Also please provide the full error message including whether there are also some Warnings or Notices and the exact name of the exception. And what is showing that error? The PHP error reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that since the db class extends PDO, when the PDO constructor throws an exception $this becomes NULL.

```
class db extends PDO {
    public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $passwd="") {
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Got PDOException\n";
            var_dump($this);
        }
    }
}


new db('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=something', 'invaliduser', 'invalidpass');
```

If you run that code you will get this output:

```
Got PDOException
NULL
```

To solve that you could remove the offending line and check if the db object is null or remove the try-catch and do the exception handling when you instantiate a new db.
Alternatively, you could rewrite the class to store the PDO object in a variable instead of extending PDO.